# When should I use "value" as an argument name?

Tags: javascript, naming, functions, naming-standards

I'm building my own utility functions to master ES6:

```
const contains = (array, value) => {
  return array.indexOf(value) > -1
}

const keys = (object) => {
  return Object.keys(object)
}

const find = (array, value) => {
  return array.filter(item => {
    return item[keys[0]] === value[keys[0]]
  })[0]
}
```

So far, I've encountered only one problem: naming my arguments. I'm checking [Lodash's](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2) naming conventions. I think it's clear when to use `array`, `object`, etc... I also saw the keyword `value`. When to use this one? When I'm unsure of the argument's type?

Comment: what language are you asking about, [tag:javascript]?

Comment: "When I'm unsure of the argument's type?" This shouldn't be the case. If you are unsure about the `type` rethink the structure & name of your `class`, `function`[...] and whether it's actually necessary.

Comment: I'm just wondering why you use arrow functions in this case... aside from the missing semi-colons.

Comment: Value is a terrible name if you know what it's for or what kind of thing it's going to be.  It's a fine name when you don't.  That's why collections use it.

Comment: @Stephan Bijzitter Less visual noise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this context, `value` is being used as a synonym for "item in an array or collection."  It's as good a guideline as any.

Comment: So one should use item or value since an array could be composed of either strings or objects?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such convention.  `value` is simply an item in an array or collection, irrespective of its type.

Answer (score 2):

Try to describe in english what the code does. The words you'll find yourself using naturally when describing in english are great candidates for the names of the corresponding variables in the code.

(Of course, you may need some grammatical/syntactical transformations. In english you may say "an array" or "the array", but you don't want `anArray` in your code - just `array` is better)

This also works the other way around - try to describe in english using the names you've chosen, and see it it sounds correct:

- `contains`: Check if a *value* is inside an *array*
- `keys`: List the field names of an *object*
- `find`: Find the index of a *value* inside an *array*

The last one sounds a bit off - so maybe `item` or `entry` will be better? Try saying them out loud and choose the one that sounds best.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Argument naming confuses me so much that I rather stick with a convention of four or five sometimes (e.g. value, key, array, string, object.)